# How should I connect to Heroku Postgres db from an external server?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

It states [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku#credentials) that it's not a good practice to connect to a heroku db using a URL like this:

```
postgres://$user:$pass@$db_host.com:5432/$db_name
```

But you should rather "fetch the database URL config var from the corresponding Heroku app when your application starts" like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a your-app) your_process
```

I want to connect to a heroku db from an external (outside heroku) node server using sequelize. How should I do that?

```
const db = new Sequelize(DATABASE_URL, {
  logging: false,
  pool: {
    max: 15,
    min: 5,
    idle: 10000,
    acquire: 10000,
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
    require: true,
  },
 },
 ssl: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With Heroku CLI, you would use `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`. To do the same thing programmatically, consult the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which states:

> You can manage your app’s config vars programmatically with the Heroku
>   Platform API using a simple HTTPS REST client and JSON data
>   structures. You need a valid Heroku access token representing a user
>   with proper permissions on the app.

The details of REST API for config vars is described in the [platform API reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars).